# Git GUI for Windows: Project folder created outside repository

Tags: git, git-gui

Created a new project within a Visual Studio solution. Noticed that the new project was not flagged for inclusion in the solution's repository. Discovered that the project folder was created at the same level as the solution folder, outside of the repository, rather than within it. How do I add this folder to the solution's repository? I really do not want to create a new repository just for this one project.

Comment: Move the folder into the project?

Comment: Take some screenshots of the file organization so we can see how it's structured?